# Which HTTP status for rendered HTML response to invalid form input

Tags: http, web, web-applications

What status code should be set to the returned html page which indicates that user has entered incorrect value in a form field ?

In REST API the obvious choice would be 422 but does this apply to a classical web page request which returns another web page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web *is* classical REST...

There's no reason not to use status code 422 here.